How can I filter and update a delta table in pyspark and save the result?
I have a delta table saved in s3, and I'm using an aws glue job to read a set of csv's into a pyspark dataframe, and then to update the delta table by appending the dataframe rows to the delta table. Before I can do that, I need to delete the rows in the delta table that have the same date as the dates that show up in the dataframe created from the csv.
I have tried the following, but it's too slow:
for date in incremental_day_list:
    bronze_df.delete(col("day") == date) 

I have searched for sql commands but I don't find any examples that can interpolate a list of strings. Also, I'm not sure if the result is saved in delta format in s3 if I run a select and filter query.
Any help would be much appreciated.

have a look at the isin method. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin

Usually you'll do an upsert in to the target delta table.
So something like:
from delta.tables import *

deltaTableBronze = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, 'path/to/your/table')
dfUpdates = spark.read.csv('path/to/your/csvs')

deltaTableBronze.alias('target').merge(
    dfUpdates.alias('updates'),
    'target.date = updates.date'
  ).whenMatchedUpdate(
    set = {
        "date": "updates.date",
        "col1": "updates.col1",
        "col2": "updates.col2",
        # ... other columns
      }
  ).whenNotMatchedInsert(
    values = {
        "date": "updates.date",
        "col1": "updates.col1",
        "col2": "updates.col2",
        # ... other columns
      }
  ).execute()


If for some reason you must use the delete, then partition the table by day (or higher level in hierarchy like week/month). And/or z-order by day column.

I tried an upsert but I got this error: UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to modify the same
target row in the Delta table in possibly conflicting ways. Do you know if there's a workaround? I could load the delta table into a spark df, delete the rows that have the same date as the updates, overwrite the entire delta table, and then append the updates but I don't think it's the most efficient way.

Reason why you're deleting is because you have newer versions of these rows, correct? If yes, then you just have to find the unique key for each row and use that in second param in merge(). This way merge() will match one row in deltaTableBronze to one in dfUpdates. Also see the bottom of my answer.
